"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defineComponent')" when i try to set up vue3-carousel on Nuxt3 App
I am geting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defineComponent')"  when i try to use the "npm install vue3-carousel" library on my nuxt3 application
i get this for other libraries i have tried. Please am i doing something wrong?
the full error stack
at /C:/Users/morri/OneDrive/Desktop/workstation/current_project/wilmorecare/node_modules/vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.js:280:27
at /C:/Users/morri/OneDrive/Desktop/workstation/current_project/wilmorecare/node_modules/vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.js:9:78
at /C:/Users/morri/OneDrive/Desktop/workstation/current_project/wilmorecare/node_modules/vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.js:10:3
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
at async ViteNodeRunner.interopedImport (/C:/Users/morri/OneDrive/Desktop/workstation/current_project/wilmorecare/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:383:28)
at async ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (/C:/Users/morri/OneDrive/Desktop/workstation/current_project/wilmorecare/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:253:24)
at async ViteNodeRunner.cachedRequest (/C:/Users/morri/OneDrive/Desktop/workstation/current_project/wilmorecare/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:189:14)
at async ViteNodeRunner.dependencyRequest (/C:/Users/morri/OneDrive/Desktop/workstation/current_project/wilmorecare/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:233:12)
at async C:\Users\morri\OneDrive\Desktop\workstation\current_project\wilmorecare\plugins\vue3-carousel.js:2:31


I am trying to use Vue Carousel library on my nuxt3 application and i have done the following
1-  npm install vue3-carousel
2- imported in i my script tag like the

<script>
import {Carousel, Slide} from 'vue3-carousel'
...


3  i also added it as a component among other components
    name: "Home App",
  components: { CTA, SocialMediaInstruction,
    Carousel,  
    Slide   

when i try to use it in my template i get like this
   <Carousel>
            <Slide>

            </Slide>


        </Carousel>


i get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defineComponent')"
i get it for every other library i try to install on my application
i'll likw to know if there is something i am doing wrong in using these libraries as this is my first project using nuxt3

Please, provide full error including error stack, it's unclear at which point it happens. "i get it for every other library i try to install on my application" - then the problem is in your own project. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , there are only truncated code snippets.

i have provided them in the question

There's something wrong with your project. The error means that "vue" import is undefined in libraries, which cannot happen under normal circumstances. This could be wrong Nuxt configuration. Please, provide a way to reproduce, a repo would be ok. Also try import from vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.es.js instead of vue3-carousel, the result could be different and also could give a hint what's wrong

To troubleshoot the carousel issue, I setup vue3-carousel in a new Nuxt app (V3.12.2). Everything worked as expected on my end.
This suggests a configuration issue with your Nuxt app, probably your app is incorrectly configured.
To help diagnose more, could you share your package.json, app.config.ts, nuxt.config.ts, App.vue.
If I may suggest you first build a solid understandig of Nuxt conventions, start with a new project build from scratch while adhering to these recommendations.

1- npm install vue3-carousel 2- imported in i my script tag like the

<script>
    import {Carousel, Slide} from 'vue3-carousel'

Please note Nuxt builds on Vue's strengths by automating common tasks. Take advantage of this by using auto-imports instead of manually importing components like this.
Nuxt has opinionated directory structure, which means there is a recommended place for every artifact of your code. Make sure your are defining components in correct directory check structure here

3 i also added it as a component among other components.

    name: "Home App",
  components: { CTA, SocialMediaInstruction,
    Carousel,  
    Slide

The above should be skipped, in Nuxt you don't need to manually define components in the components option.
